# ValueError: Only one class present in y_true. ROC AUC score is not defined in that case

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pytorch

I want to calculate AUROC using dataset with all instance zero. However, the following error occurred:

ValueError: Only one class present in y_true. ROC AUC score is not defined in that case

```
def computeAUROC (dataGT, dataPRED, classCount):

    outAUROC = []

    datanpGT = dataGT.cpu().numpy()
    datanpPRED = dataPRED.cpu().numpy()

    for i in range(classCount):
        outAUROC.append(roc_auc_score(datanpGT[:, i], datanpPRED[:, i]))

    return outAUROC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have an [ROC curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic) without both positive and negative examples in your dataset. With only one class in the dataset, you cannot measure your false-positive rate, and therefore cannot plot an ROC curve. This is why you get this error message.